# Expected number of games played in a game with 'win by two' rule.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

Calvin and Hobbes play a match consisting of a series of games, where Calvin has
probability p of winning each game (independently). They play with a “win by two””
rule: the first player to win two games more than his opponent wins the match. What is the expected number of games played?

My attempt:
I use Markov chains. Let $S$ denote that starting state, $W$ and $L$ denote the states where Calvin and Hobbes win respectively. Then, I have
$$\mu_S = 1+ p\mu_W+q\mu_L $$
$$\mu_W = 1+ q\mu_S $$
$$\mu_L = 1+ p\mu_S $$
where $\mu_j$ denote the expected number of games from state $j$. Solving the system, I get the solution $\mu_S = \frac{2}{1-2pq}$ which I think is correct. I however would like to know how to approach it with geometric distribution instead of Markov chains. I read one solution where the number of games is given as $1+\text{Geom}(p^2+q^2)$ but I do not understand it. My understanding is that for the game to stop, the required probability is $p^2 + q^2$ since this is the probability that either Calvin or Hobbes win two games in a row. How to use this information in a Geometric random variable?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, those two answers don't match.  With $p=q=\frac 12$, your result is $\frac 2{1-\frac 12}=4$ but the other would give $1+\frac 1{\frac 12}=3$, for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the first two games.  There are three possible outcomes:  $C$ wins, $H$ wins, the game restarts.  Phrased differently, there are two outcomes each of which takes two turns:  either someone wins (probability $p^2+q^2$) or the game restarts.  Thus you can think of the game as a binomial process where each move consists of two games.  It follows that the desired process (waiting for a winner to emerge) is: $$2\times \text {Geom}(p^2+q^2)$$ which is to say: $$P(X=2n)=P(\text {Geom}(p^2+q^2)=n)$$ which implies that the expectation is  $$2\times \text E[\text {Geom}(p^2+q^2)]$$ and the desired expectation is therefore $$\frac 2{p^2+q^2}$$ which is easily seen to agree with your Markov result.

Comment: Thanks. Why is it $2*Geom(p^2+q^2)$? Since $p^2+q^2$ captures the probability that C wins or H wins, what does multiplying by 2 really capture?

Comment: As I wrote, the factor of $2$ captures the fact that each round in the associated binomial game consists of two rounds of Calvinball.  Again:  a single trial of the new game has exactly two outcomes; either somebody wins both or each player wins $1$ in which case we are back to the start.

Comment: I should stress:  this trick only works with the "win by two" rule. If you impose a "rule by three" rule,  then it is not true that the game must reset if the winner isn't decided in the first three games (indeed, it can not reset after three games).  The game need never reset...it can go $CCHCHCH\cdots$ as long as you like without ever defining a winner nor returning to the starting state.  Of course, the Markov methodology works perfectly well in this case (since we must revisit some state, just not necessarily the starting state).

Comment: Thanks. Accepted the answer.