# Series of games

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

Bill and Mark play a series of games until one of the players has won two games more than the other player. Any game is won by Bill with probability $p$ and by Mark with probability $q = 1 − p$. The results of the games are independent of each other. What is the probability that Bill will be the winner of the match?

Let $A=[$Bill wins the 1° game$]\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(A)=p$ and $B=[$Bill wins the 2° game$]\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(B)=p$, so $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)=p^2$.

Let $\bar{A}=[$Mark wins the 1° game$]\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(\bar{A})=q$ and $\bar{B}=[$Mark wins the 2° game$]\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(\bar{B})=q$, so $\mathbb{P}(\bar{A}\cap \bar{B})=q^2$.

Since $Z=[$tie$]\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(Z)=\mathbb{P}[(A\cap \bar{B})\cup (\bar{A}\cap B)]=2pq$, we have $H=[$Bill wins$]=\frac{p^2}{1-2pq}$.

Now I have a question. Is it possible to solve the problem setting

- $X=[$# games won by Bill$]\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(X=x)=\binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$
- $Y=[$# games won by Mark$]\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(Y=y)=\binom{n}{y}q^y(1-q)^{n-y}$

? Because I'm stuck when $\mathbb{P}(X\geq Y+2)=$

$\sum_{y=0}^{n}\binom{n}{y}q^y(1-q)^{n-y}\sum_{x=y+2}^{\infty}\binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}=pq^n(1+\frac{q}{p})^n\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\binom{n}{s+y+2}(\frac{p}{q})^{s+y+2}$

with $s=x-y-2$.

If not, why?

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: Problems like this are best solved with Markov chains or with recursions..see, e.g., [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3809895/expected-number-of-games-played-in-a-game-with-win-by-two-rule/3809932#3809932).  That question concerns the expected length of the match, but the various probabilities can be handled the same way.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to see how your approach can work, since simply knowing that $B$ wins more games out of a large number $n$ doesn't tell us that $B$ won the match (after all, $M$ might have won the first two games but lost the next $n-2$).

Your question is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3809895/expected-number-of-games-played-in-a-game-with-win-by-two-rule/3809932#3809932).

That question concerns the expected length of the match, but the probabilities can be handled in the same manner.

Let $\psi$ denote the probability that $B$ eventually wins the match. We consider the first two games and note that there are three possible outcomes:  either $B$ wins ($p^2$), $M$ wins ($(1-p)^2$) or they split the two games and the match resets ($2p(1-p)$).  It follows that $$\psi=p^2\times 1 +(1-p)^2\times 0 + 2p(1-p)\times \psi$$ which implies $$ \boxed {\psi=\frac {p^2}{1-2p(1-p)}}$$

Sanity checks: For all probabilities $p$ we get $0≤\psi≤1$ as we should. if $p=0$ this yields $0$, if $p=1$ this yields $1$, and if $p=\frac 12$ this yields $\frac 12$.  If $\overline {\psi}$ denotes the result if we switch $p, 1-p$ (so $\overline {\psi}$ is the probability that $M$ wins the match) we check that $$\psi+\overline {\psi}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

The probability you're interested in is smaller than $\mathbb{P}(X\geq Y+2)$ because in addition you also require that for all subsequences of games (with #games <$n$) have difference in wins that is at most 1 (for odd #games) or is tied (for even #games) for you to play $n$ games